# Draw 10 random questions from database in google form

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

The question is very similar to this [Google Form random questions from a bank, different every time Form is opened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59770233/google-form-random-questions-from-a-bank-different-every-time-form-is-opened) and [Dynamic/Random questions on Google Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48786137/dynamic-random-questions-on-google-form) .

I have a database of 50 multiple choice questions (with a,b,c,d options) and I would like to draw 10 questions from this database every time I open the google form.

Any updates on how to do this?

Comment: Check this similar post: [How to fetch data from Google Sheets and show it on Google Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65093674/how-to-fetch-data-from-google-sheets-and-show-it-on-google-forms) Then you can use [installable triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) like `onFormSubmit`as `onOpen `is not applicable when opening Google Forms in response view.

Comment: `I would like to draw 10 questions from this database every time I open the google form.` `Any updates on how to do this?` As you are asking about _updates_, I figure that you are referring to whether one can create a dynamic link between Sheets and Forms. The answer to that question is "no". One cannot update Forms questions from Sheets on the fly. OTOH, you _can_ update Forms questions after each submission (subject to concurrent submissions); this is the approach mentioned by @Serenity.